# solidity and react - can't get manager

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, solidity, web3js

I have this contract written in solidity and deployed to https://rinkeby.infura.io/:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;

    constructor() {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);

        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function random() private view returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encode(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players)));        
    }

    function pickWinner() public restricted {
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        payable(players[index]).transfer(address(this).balance);
        players = new address[](0);
    }

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    function getPlayers() public view returns(address[] memory) {
        return players;
    }
}
```

And react code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import lottery from './lottery';

function App() {
    const [manager, setManager] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();
            console.log(manager)

            setManager(manager);
        })();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Lottery Contract</h2>
            <p>This contract is managed by {manager}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

But when it logs manager it's an empty array, and it should log the address of the manager.
Lottery.js contains a connection to the deployed contract as well as abi and address where contract is deployed:

```
const abi = [{
        inputs: [],
        stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
        type: 'constructor',
        constant: undefined,
        payable: undefined,
        signature: 'constructor'
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: 'enter',
        outputs: [],
        stateMutability: 'payable',
        type: 'function',
        constant: undefined,
        payable: true,
        signature: '0xe97dcb62'
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: 'getPlayers',
        outputs: [
            [Object]
        ],
        stateMutability: 'view',
        type: 'function',
        constant: true,
        payable: undefined,
        signature: '0x8b5b9ccc'
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: 'manager',
        outputs: [
            [Object]
        ],
        stateMutability: 'view',
        type: 'function',
        constant: true,
        payable: undefined,
        signature: '0x481c6a75'
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: 'pickWinner',
        outputs: [],
        stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
        type: 'function',
        constant: undefined,
        payable: undefined,
        signature: '0x5d495aea'
    },
    {
        inputs: [
            [Object]
        ],
        name: 'players',
        outputs: [
            [Object]
        ],
        stateMutability: 'view',
        type: 'function',
        constant: true,
        payable: undefined,
        signature: '0xf71d96cb'
    }
];

export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

compile.js

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const lotteryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Lottery.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(lotteryPath, 'utf8');

const input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        Lottery: {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': ['abi', 'evm.bytecode']
            }
        }
    }
}

const contract = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts.Lottery.Lottery;

module.exports = contract;
```

deploy.js

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const { abi, evm } = require('./compile');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    '12 word secret',
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/812.....adsf12'
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async() => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account:', accounts[0]);
    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
        .deploy({ data: evm.bytecode.object })
        .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });

    console.log(result._jsonInterface);
    console.log(`Contract deployed to: ${result.options.address}`);
}

deploy();
```

I run node deploy.js and then get the address and abi and put it in my frontend application.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code on remix and it works:

[image]

I think the problem is with the contract creation. Most likely your `abi` is causing error. abi is the way how we interact with the contract, so somehow it is not correct abi

in your abi take a look at `manager`:

```
 inputs: [],
        name: 'manager',
        outputs: [
            [Object]
        ],
```

I do not think that outputs should be `Object`. you probably created abi before and then changed the contract code but forgot to create abi again.

- this is from documentation

  myContract.deploy({
  // DATA SHOULD BE STARTING WITH "0x"
  data: '0x12345...',
  arguments: [123, 'My String']
  })

try this:

```
const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
    .deploy({ data:"0x" + evm.bytecode.object })
```

- based on [solc documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc), `input` should be like this:

  ```
   var input = {
      language: "Solidity",
      // you are passing Lottery
      sources: {
        "Lottery.sol": {
          content: source,
        },
      },
      settings: {
        outputSelection: {
          "*": {
            "*": ["*"],
          },
        },
      },
    };
  ```

Comment: I added the abi, do you see where is the problem?

Comment: @AndrijaGajic I updated the answer

Comment: @AndrijaGajic I updated the answer

Comment: I deployed the contract again, and the abi is the same. Still, it doesn't make sense to return an array of objects as an output, I don't know why it does that.

Comment: can u pls share the code how you are creating abi code?

Comment: I added the script for contract deployment and contract compilation

Comment: Tried with 0x, but still now working, and then I logged evm.bytecode.object and it already starts with 0x, so it's not up to that, it's something else

Comment: @AndrijaGajic try to change the input the way I changed on code

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work, it returns the same abi

Comment: @AndrijaGajic   const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)   abi that you are passing must be json Interface. can u check if it is?

Comment: Finally, I solved it, here's how: I took my contract to remix ide compiled it and clicked abi button to copy the abi, pasted that abi in my frontend app and now it works

Comment: @AndrijaGajic it is a different abi, right?

Answer (score 0):

Works if your stringify abi

console.log(JSON.stringify(abi))